# File based SVN repository over a network

Tags: svn

I would like to create an file based SVN repository over the network. Is it possible to access the repository by the all the clients connected to the local network? Is it possible to give per-directory permission to that repository?

To be more precise, I have five computers connected in the network. I would like to keep the repository in my home account. There are other users who have a user account to login into the network. I am amongst those users. Is it possible for me to create file based SVN and give per-directory user permissions to those users?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the SVN Book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/) online, there you will find a chapter named [Built-in Authentication and Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth) that explains how to do what you want.

There is also a section named [Path-based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) that shows how to grant read/write privileges over specific paths.

You can expose your server via several protocols. The simpler is using the svn protocol. You can also use SSH or if you can configure your own Apache Server, you can expose it through HTTP protocol.

All this is well explained in the book. I actually learned to configure my own SVN server through HTTP Apache server after a few hours of reading and experimentation.

**EDIT-1**

If what you intend is direct access, you can use file-based URLs to achieve this. This is also explained in the book in the section [Subversion Repository URLs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls).

Comment: Actually my question was , if i can use file:// based repository access instead of  running **svnserve** daemon and enabling those per-directory permission in those other server configurations.

Comment: Well, you can use file-based URLs (i.e. svn list file:///var/svn/repos) provided that the path to the folder where the repo resides is accessible to everyone. In this case you do not have a server, just the repo.

Answer (score 1):

The permission on the `file://` area will only be valid for the repository access but not for the permission on the contents of the repository. Furthermore the access via `file://` should be done only from the server, not from clients. So the best solution is to install an `svnserve` or Apache to serve as an SVN server. For Windows, etc. `visualsvn.com` (server) or [CollabNet Subversion Edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CollabNet#Commercial_Offerings) might be a good alternative.